# How to update the configuration for eslint after upgrade angular 11 to 12

Tags: migration, eslint, angular11, angular12, eslintrc

Migrate the angular version from 11 to 12.

*Angular.json*

```
  "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-cls/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "projects/test/**/*.ts",
              "projects/test/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        },
```

Package.json

```
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "1.2.0",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "1.2.0",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "1.2.0",
"@angular-eslint/schematics": "^12.1.0",
"@angular-eslint/template-parser": "1.2.0",
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

install

```
ng add @angular-eslint/schematics
```

after this use below command

```
ng g @angular-eslint/schematics:convert-tslint-to-eslint --remove-tslint-if-no-more-tslint-targets --ignore-existing-tslint-config
```

if you have multiple project use below command

```
ng g @angular-eslint/schematics:convert-tslint-to-eslint {{your project name}} --remove-tslint-if-no-more-tslint-targets --ignore-existing-tslint-config
```